# How to update the query reference of a firebase recycler adapter?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I have a `RecyclerView` bound to a `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. I need to update the data displayed based on a value set by the user using a `spinner`.

Something like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("data");
Query query = ref.orderByChild("index").startAt(loadPreferences()).endAt(loadPreferences());
final Adapter fireAdapter = new Adapter(Model.class, R.layout.model_card, Adapter.FireViewHolder.class, query);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String selectedIndex = String.valueOf(adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i));
            savePreferences(selectedIndex);
            Query newQuery = ref.orderByChild("index").startAt(selectedIndex).endAt(selectedIndex));
            fireAdapter.updateQuery(newQuery); //This is what i'm looking for
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

My adapter:

```
class Adapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model, Adapter.FireViewHolder> {

Adapter(Class<Model> modelClass, int modelLayout, Class<FireViewHolder> viewHolderClass, Query ref) {
    super(modelClass, modelLayout, viewHolderClass, ref);
}

@Override
protected void populateViewHolder(FireViewHolder viewHolder, Model model, int position) {
    viewHolder.text.setText(model.getText());
}

static class FireViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView text;

    public FireViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    }
}

public void updateQuery(Query newQuery){
     ???????
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find a proper answer but as a temporary workaround just creating a new adapter and setting it to the `RecyclerView` works. Still feel there should be a more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: would you be the greatest and share how you tweaked your way around?

Answer (score 0):

Use FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter the solution is implemented. Or merge the same code change to your app base.

https://firebaseui.com/docs/android/index.html?com/firebase/ui/FirebaseRecyclerViewAdapter.html